# How to use Laravel sanctum with Breeze

Tags: vue.js, breeze, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

I have installed Laravel Breeze and then Sanctum. But, it is not working as it should. Please guide me, how can I set up it?
I want to create the admin panel with Laravel Breeze and Vue application for the front users.

Answer (score 0):

For a start you can install Breeze with Vue + Inertia scaffolding unless you're implementing everything by hand using API calls with Sanctum. First option is easier to implement.

```
php artisan breeze:install vue
php artisan migrate
npm install
npm run dev
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze